# Show data and calculation of the php table

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a php file which want to print out the total number of email (total),the number of email sent(sent) and the number of email haven't not sent for each day. Here's my php file as follows

```
<?php      
    $total =0;
    $sent =0;
    $pending = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT `sflag` , `thedate` FROM `ecard2008` WHERE `thedate` >= '2013-12-12'";
    $list_mysql = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();
    while($list = mysql_fetch_array($list_array)) {
        $sflag = $list['sflag'];
        $date = $list['thedate'];
        if ($sflag == 0) {
            $pending = $pending + 1;
        }
        else {
            $sent = $sent + 1;
        }
        $total = $total + 1;
    }
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Daily volume</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
    </tr>";

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $total . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sent . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $pending . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Unfortunately, the output only show the table and the first row of the table. The number of email cannot be shown. What can I do to show these number.

Comment: $sflag is the declaration of the new variable that hold the selection of sflag ,which is from my db

Comment: Ok, but what does sFlag stand for? what is its meaning?

Comment: The meaning is to check whether the email have been sent or not. If sFlag =0, that means the email have not sent

Comment: `if ($sflag==0)` instead of `if ($sflag=0)`

Comment: It still cannot solve my problem althrough make this change

Comment: is `$edate` defined yet?

Comment: It is '$date', not '$edate'.

Comment: what happens if the query doesn't run? how do you see errors? Try writing a bad syntax query and see what happens!

Comment: The php cannot display the webpage without any reason. Therefore, I cannot see any error why I cannot print the table in the page

Comment: try something like `$list_mysql = mysql_query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
if (!$list_mysql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}` Also mysql_ methods are deprecated, look into using mysqli or PDO

Comment: After trying $list_mysql = mysql_query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); if (!$list_mysql) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }, the page have not made any changes in the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... You try using mysqli,

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$sql = "SELECT 'thedate', count(sflag) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN sflag = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'sent', SUM(CASE WHEN sflag= '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'pending' FROM 'ecard2008' WHERE 'thedate' >= '2013-12-12' group by 'thedate'";

$list_mysql = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Daily volume</th>
<th>Sent</th>
<th>Pending</th>
</tr>";


while($list = mysql_fetch_array($list_mysql)) {

echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>" . $list['thedate']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['total'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['sent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['pending'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some basic debugging change this line:

```
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($list_array)){
```

to this:

```
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($list_mysql)){
```

There is no variable called $list_array.

Comment: It still cannot solve my problem. The program still execute the same output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php      
$sql = "SELECT 'thedate', count(sflag) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN sflag = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'sent', SUM(CASE WHEN sflag= '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'pending' FROM 'ecard2008' WHERE 'thedate' >= '2013-12-12' group by 'thedate'";

$list_mysql = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Daily volume</th>
    <th>Sent</th>
    <th>Pending</th>
</tr>";


while($list = mysql_fetch_array($list_mysql)) {

echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>" . $list['thedate']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['total'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['sent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $list['pending'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: again the sql still has the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ecard2008' WHERE 'thedate' >= '2013-12-12' group by 'thedate' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: 'thedate'>='2013-12-12' means the date can be found on or after 2013-12-12. That is, I want to print out the data after 2013-12-12

Comment: Ok... Kindly check my new answer with mysqli. It should work. otherwise... you have to check your field names and verify again